# Django Model Many to Many Alternative

Tags: django, django-models

I have a setup where I have several models two of which are `Option` and `Project`. `Options` represent select options for several fields in my application and store about 1000 (default) values. What I now want to achive is that `Projects` can have their own set of `Options`, that means they will see the default set of the options when they start a new `Project`. However they can **delete** some Options which then will not show in their Project (but stay in the database) as well as **add** custom options to their Project (which other should not be able to see). The common use case is that users might want to keep 99% of the default `Options` so they will delete 10 and maybe add 10.

How do I model the described case? Would I need to have a ManyToMany Field `Project <-> Option` that I would populate with all `Options` on project creation or is there a better, less space consuming way you can think of, e.g. somehow store deleted ids somewhere and find a way to show default `Options` + project specific `Options`?

My models are like so:

```
class Option(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="selectoptions", blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    #we can have nested selectoptions
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='projects')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have your Project model as such

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True)
    anyother field you wish to have
```

and you can continue with the Option model you have, that should suffice.

Now lets say you have options 1,2,3,4,5 and projects A and B

**A** may have options 1,2,3 and **B** may have options 2,3,4,5.

Further, you dont want to have option 1 in your project **A**, you simply remove it from M2M field by this statement

```
projectA.options.remove(option1)
```

So, you have deleted option1 from your project but it still persists in the database, you can add same option1 to projectB by using statement

```
projectB.options.add(option1)
```

So, now when you do

```
projectA.options.all()
```

your output will option2, option3

and `projectB.options.all()` will give option1, option2, option3, option4, option5.

I hope I have explained properly, in case if its unclear leave a comment, will be happy to help.

**Edit:** and yes this is how it should be in your case unless you get alternative way of doing it.

**Edit 2**:

Post the question update, you can remove options as M2M field from Project and have a separate model by name ProjectOption. It may be like,

```
class ProjectOption(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    option  = models.ForeignKey(Option)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You will still have to populate it, its a one time operation for you. So now, you will have your default options per project, if user chooses to delete one you can either set is_deleted=True or actually delete it. This will provide you with details of options that are deleted(only when you dont actually delete object but just set is_deleted=True).

Comment: The problem is that when I create a new Project, I would always have to do: `selectOptions = Option.objects.all() newProject.options.add(*selectOptions)` That would be a huge overhead as it would create database entries for all of the items. I would prefer to store ids of deleted selectoptions somehow and on top of that maybe recieve only selectOptions from default project + selectOptions of the current project

Comment: May I know how is that a problem? and why you have to do newProject.options.add(*selectOptions). See, options are separate entity. When you create a newProject it wont have any options to it right? So, its M2M options field wont have anything. Populate it only when the user chooses to add that option.

Comment: When you do newProject.options.add(*selectOptions), you are needlessly populating newProject with options and then asking user to remove unwanted ones when it should be like let user add/remove whatever he wants.

Comment: Yes but in my case. It would be that useres might keep 995 options of the default options while roughly removing 5 and adding 5. clariefied my question

Comment: Okay, now  I understand your need for adding selectOptions upon newProject creation, but still its a one time operation you will have to do else how would you provide default options. See my edit for updated answer.